# Adding extra functionality to Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

It's a fairly simple idea, but I'm not sure where I should start reading.

All I want to do is add an extra action to a model in the Django Admin.

For example, I have a basic client management system, in that I have models for Clients, Companies, and Invoices to keep track of who owes what. All I want to do is add an action or button that when used, pulls information from the Invoices, Clients, and possibly Companies and then puts that information into a PDF document.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. How do you want this to happen and where? On what page will this button be? Have you looked in [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override your admin templates for each of your models to add a button => [Overriding Admin Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

To generate a PDF define a view that is called once your button is pressed. Make sure to set the [right permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization) for your admin users.